# How to change key name in a JSON at logstash level?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I am using logstash to ship json data to elasticsearch. But I need to change the key name of a particular key at logstash level before shipping to ElasticSearch.

Is it possible to do so? If yes, do I need to include some plugins for logstash?

Original data:
{"keyA": "dataA", "keyB": "dataB"}

ElasticSearch data:
{"keyC": "dataA", "keyB": "dataB"}

Comment: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-mutate.html#plugins-filters-mutate-rename

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible.
Use the [rename configuration option on the mutate filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-mutate.html#plugins-filters-mutate-rename) to rename one or more fields.
By default, it should already come included with Logstash.

Example:

```
 filter {
  mutate {
    # Renames the 'keyA' field to 'KeyC'
    rename => { "keyA" => "keyC" }
  }
}
```